# How to import data from website and use it in my web page using JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to use particular data of some website and show it my webpage.

I wanted to make an web article about the best Youtube Channels. Surely I have to write information about these channel.
For example, There is a youTube channel called "Example" and this channel has url like:

`https://www.youtube.com/user/justforexample`

I need amount of subscribers of it. In page source, it is inside tag:

`<yt-formatted-string id="subscriber-count" class="style-scope ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer">4.5M subscribers</yt-formatted-string>`

(actually i dont know if there is tag like that but tag maybe not only , it maybe `<span>` or  `<div>`)

What I want is numbers. It should be in real time. 
For instance, in 2020 this channel has 4.5M subscribers, after few years it turn out to be 5.8M.

Above was just example, it may not be only Youtube page, any website.

I know JS and jQuery and hope you help me :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try sending an HTTP GET request to that url

Read about jQuery ajax function for more information: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Note that additional headers might be needed, try and analyze the response